# Python unittest module command line arguments without main

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, python-unittest

I am trying to pass in command line arguments to my unit tests. However, I am not using an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, as everything is packaged as a relative path. So calling `python path/to/test.py` will throw this error:

```
from .setup import Utilities
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I am calling the tests as follows: `python -m unittest test_file.test_name`. This startups with the `setUpModule()` function. However, it seems that the command line parsing happens before that function somewhere in the unit test library, so passing in anything that is not a module throws an error. So doing: `python -m unittest test_file.test_name arg1` throws: `ImportError: No module named arg1`.

Is there any way around this, without having to use `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Answer (score 1):

Asking `unittest` for help gives the following message

```
$ ../python3 -m unittest -h
Usage: python3 -m unittest [options]

Options:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose   Verbose output
  -q, --quiet     Quiet output
  -f, --failfast  Stop on first fail or error
  -c, --catch     Catch ctrl-C and display results so far
  -b, --buffer    Buffer stdout and stderr during tests
```

The `unittest` doc describes these further.  So `unittest` takes some options (and even one subcommand, `discover`).  But I don't see evidence of a way to pass options through to your own module.

Playing around with `-m unittest` a bit more, it is evident that `unittest` tries to parse any `options` (e.g. `-z`).  And everything else like your `arg1` is part of the list of modules to test.